# SAS - Copy the column values of a row to another row based on a specific condition

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I want to copy the column values of a row to another row based on some condition using SAS data step or Proc SQL. I have the following data:

[image]

Now I want to copy Field1, Field2 and Field3 in the second row from  the first row since they have same Member_ID, Date1 and Group1. The output should look like:
[image]

Comment: What is the rule that determines when you need to copy data?  Do you only want to replace missing values?  Why are you showing those two rows in that order? Could they instead be in the other order so that the row with the missing values is before the row with the non-missing values?

Comment: @Tom We need to copy data in case we have blank Filed1, Field2 and Field3. It should have the same value based on Member_ID, Date1 and Group1. If these values are not same, then we cannot copy the values... The order does not matter as long as the data is copied.

Comment: What if for `Member_ID=103 Date1='20mar2022'd GROUP='D'`, you have rows with `Field1='' Field2='' Field3=''` with `Field1='one' Field2='two' Field3=''` with `Field1='mono' Field2='' Field3='trio'` and again  with `Field1='' Field2='' Field3=''`, in this order?

Comment: @DirkHorsten Actually in this problem statement, we won't have any different field values. So for example, if the Field1=one, Field2=two and Field3=' ', then we need to copy it along the same Member_ID, Date1 and Group1. There will not be different set of values within the same Member_ID, Date1 and Group1.

Comment: Is performance an issue **?** Is the dataset sorted on Member_ID, Date1 and Group1 **?** Does the observation with the most fields filled in always preceed **?** _(Next time you ask a question, be more specific, please)_

Comment: @DirkHorsten Performance won't be any issue and yes the dataset is sorted based on Member_ID, Date1 and Group1...No, the blank field can precede as well.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I don't have access to a SAS environment right now, so you'll probably need to debug this code a bit.

This code might resolve your issue, though I've only written code for fixing Field1. It should be straightforward to resolve the issue for all three fields. I've called the dataset "*data_copy*".

```
/* Sort so that the record with non-missing values are first within its group */
proc sort data=data_copy out=data_copy_sorted;
    by Member_ID DATE1 GROUP1 descending Field1;
run;

/* If a retained variable */
data data_copy_corrected;
    set data_copy_sorted;
    by Member_ID DATE1 GROUP1;
    if _N_=1 then do;
        lenth field1_retained $ 256;    /* You probably want to add Field1's length here */
        retain field1_retained '';
    end;

    /* Retain value if first record within group (only need innermost group variable) */
    if first.GROUP1 then do;
        field1_retained = Field1;
    end;
    else do;
        if Field1 = '' then Field1 = field1_retained;
    end;
run;
```

You could also use the LAG function:
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/ds2ref/n1kafye91ndieyn182cc6gu441jh.htm